# Pass Array From Select Into xmlhttp

Tags: javascript, php

I want to pass an array of values from my `select` into the `xmlhttp.open` request below so I can parse the variables in the new page. How can this be achieved? I attempted the syntax below, but it throws a 500 error when the button is pressed.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function GetData() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var hiredate = document.getElementById("hiredate").value; 
    var termdate = document.getElementById("termdate").value
    var arr = document.getElementById("bq").value;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
           if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
               document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
           }
           else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
              alert('There was an error 400');
           }
           else {
               alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
           }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "Query.php?hiredate="+hiredate+"&termdate="+termdate+"&array="+arr, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<select name="bq" size="12" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1">
<option value="HireDate">HireDate</option>
<option value="TermDate">TermDate</option>
<option value="Dept">Dept</option>
<option value="Manager">Manager</option></select>
Start Date: <input type="date" name="hiredate" id="hiredate">
End Date: <input type="date" name="termdate" id="termdate">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="ajaxButton" onclick="GetData()">
<div id="data">
```

**EDIT**

This is my `Query.php` - I omitted the actual connection to the server as I know that is sound

```
<?php

    $hiredate = $_GET['hiredate'];
    $termdate = $_GET['termdate'];
    $sql = '';
    $selected_fields = array();   
    foreach ($_GET['array'] as $selectedOption){
        $selected_fields[] = $selectedOption;
    }
    if(!empty($selected_fields)){
        $fields = implode(',', $selected_fields);
        $sql = 'SELECT '.$fields.' from testtable'; 
    }

    $sql = $sql & "WHERE hiredate = $hiredate AND termdate = $termdate";
    echo $sql
?>
```

Comment: WHat is the error description?

Comment: What happens if you try to manually navigate to Quary.php?hiredate="+hiredate+"&termdate="+termdate+"&array="+arr ? Do you get a 500 error?

Comment: @JulienB. - no it shows the .php code in the file itself. -- I auto assumed it was due to not being able to pass an array the way I set up in the querystring.

Comment: Hum, your server as php enabled?

Comment: @JulienB. - yes, other .php pages work exactly as they should.

Comment: Are you using <? instead of <?php in that file? Can you post this file code?

Comment: Oh! I missed that multiple option, try using square brackets as so : <select name="bq[]" size="12" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1">

Comment: Also, are you missing the </select>?

Comment: I added in the closing `</select>` and also the `bq[]` now the page loads, but no data is returned.

Comment: What if you print_r($_GET['array']) before your foreach loop in your php file? Note: This is just for debugging...

Comment: Oh! You are trying to concatenate your strings with &. Use . (dot). $sql = $sql . "WHERE hiredate = $hiredate AND termdate = $termdate";

Comment: Or even better with $sql .= "WHERE hiredate = $hiredate AND termdate = $termdate";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137777/discussion-between-julien-b-and-bellhopbydayametuercoderbynigh).